# What is "a very understandably, deeply inducing prospect"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "inducing prospect" mean here?

> "... . Being inside our minds is for most of us and very understandably, a deeply anxiety *inducing prospect*."

Source [1:25s](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Df55QO2isoKM&ved=2ahUKEwjMs-SNmNTeAhWEj1QKHVlpBgcQtwIwAXoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0iVevP5_rkwciygSTYmBbf)

Comment: The phrase is **anxiety-inducing**, meaning something that causes anxiety.  It should be a hyphenated word when written.

Comment: I take it that you understand that it induces anxiety but are asking about what it means to be "**deeply** inducing"? How does **deeply** go with the verb **induce**?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo   Yes, how does it go?

Comment: I don't think it goes well at all.  IMO, the phrase "a deeply anxiety inducing prospect" is somewhat clumsy. It would be better to use the verb **induces**:  *For most of us, being inside our own minds induces deep anxiety.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo   Induces "a deep anxiety", or just "deep anxiey"? Is there any difference?

Comment: There is no real *practical* difference, merely a grammatical one.  The indefinite article casts anxiety as a plural thing:  for example, there's mild anxiety, vague anxiety, deep anxiety, acute anxiety, chronic anxiety, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have misparsed this (complicated) structure.

"For most of us and very understandably" is a (coordinated) adverbial phrase, that applies to the whole predication.

The prospect is not "inducing", but "anxiety inducing".

The whole structure is:

> It is [[for most of us] and [very understandably]] a [[deeply [anxiety-inducing]] prospect.